# Finding a triangle angle based on side length equality

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Consider the triangle ABC with angle A being 70 degrees, and the side lengths satisfying:

$BC^2=AC(AB+AC)$

Is there any intuitive way of finding the measure of angle B? I noticed that the given equality is similar to the Pythagorean Theorem, but not quite.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

From the given $BC^2=AC(AB+AC)$, we have from the sine rule

$$\sin^2A=\sin B (\sin C+ \sin B)$$

Note

$$\begin{align}
& \sin^2A-\sin B (\sin C+ \sin B)\\
=& \sin^2A-\sin^2 B- \sin B \sin C\\
=& \frac12(\cos 2B -\cos 2A) - \sin B \sin (A+B)\\
=& \sin (A-B)\sin (A+B) -\sin B \sin (A+B)\\
=& \sin (A+B)[\sin (A-B) -\sin B]=0\\
\end{align}$$
which leads to $\sin (A-B) =\sin B$ or $ B=\frac12A=35^\circ$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a = BC, b = AC$, and $c = AB$. Using the cosine rule we have:

$$a^2  = b^2+c^2 - 2bc \cos 70º$$

and since $a^2 = c \cdot b + b^2$, then:

$$c \cdot b + b^2 =  b^2+c^2 - 2bc \cos 70º$$
$$bc =  c^2 - 2bc \cos 70º$$

and this information allows you to find $b$ in terms of $c$.

Then substitute back into the cosine rule which allows you to relate $a$ with $b$. A straightforward application of the sine rule will allow you to find angle $B$.

I get that $B = 35º$.

---

Edit: there is a proof on [AoPS](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h477184p2672014) (and another proof [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1183443p5738517)) that if $\angle A = 2 \angle B$, then $BC^2 = AC(AB+AC)$. This result gives $B = 35º$.